# Values of new Inputs (by appendChild) are not transfered by the form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom, input

I want to create an dataset that contains a variable number of pairs of additional information. 
This is how i realised it, for example for edit one if this datasets:

- with sql + php i print the old datapairs and a new clean dataset (2 inputs)
- if the user need more than 2 new inputs, he can klick to "more data" and an javascript appends 2 newinputs

This works fine, but if the user submits the form it dont transfers the new inputs.

I think the code will explain it a bit better :)

Here the js ...

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript"> 
    input_daten_de_nr=<?php echo count($produkte_daten_de)+2; ?>; 
    function new_input_data_de(){

        var data_input_container = document.getElementById("dynamic_input_daten_de");

        input_daten_de_nr++; 

        var input_1 = document.createElement('input');
        input_1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input_1.setAttribute('id',   'daten_de_'+input_daten_de_nr);
        input_1.setAttribute('name',   'daten_de['+input_daten_de_nr+']');
        input_1.setAttribute('value', '');
        data_input_container.appendChild(input_1);

        input_daten_de_nr++; 

        var input_2 = document.createElement('input');
        input_2.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input_2.setAttribute('id',   'daten_de_'+input_daten_de_nr);
        input_2.setAttribute('name',   'daten_de['+input_daten_de_nr+']');
        input_2.setAttribute('value', '');
        data_input_container.appendChild(input_2);

        var input_br = document.createElement('br');
        data_input_container.appendChild(input_br);

    }
</script>
```

... here the form ...

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
    <div id='dynamic_input_daten_de'> 
        <?php
        $number = 1;
        if($produkte_daten_de) foreach($produkte_daten_de AS $daten_de){

            echo "<input type='text' id='daten_de_".$number."' name='daten_de[".$number."]' value='".$daten_de["text"]."'>";
            $number++;

            if(($number % 2)==1) echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<input type='text' id='daten_de_".$number."' name='daten_de[".$number."]' value=''>";
        $number++;
        echo "<input type='text' id='daten_de_".$number."' name='daten_de[".$number."]' value=''>";
        $number++;
        echo "<br>";
        ?>
    </div> 
    <h3 onClick="new_input_data_de();"> <u style="cursor:pointer;">more data</u></h3>
    ...
</form>
```

... and here the Code at runtime, after one click to "more data" ...

```
<div id="dynamic_input_daten_de">
<input id="daten_de_1" type="text" value="" name="daten_de[1]">
<input id="daten_de_2" type="text" value="" name="daten_de[2]">
<br>
<input id="daten_de_3" type="text" name="daten_de[3]" value="">
<input id="daten_de_4" type="text" name="daten_de[4]" value="">
<br>
</div>
```

.. and the print_r($_POST) anfter submitting ...

```
Array
(
    ...
    [daten_de] => Array
        (
            [1] => a
            [2] => b
        )

    ...
)
```

Maybe some one got an approach?

---

EDIT: I changed my code, but this don't solves the problem ;(

(thanx @ Dima Shevtchuk for this better looking code.)

```
  <script type="text/JavaScript"> 
    daten_de_nr=<?php echo count($produkte_daten_de)+2; ?>; 
    $( "#new_input_data_de" ).click(function() {
        daten_de_nr++; 
        var e1 = "<input type='text' value='' id='daten_de["+daten_de_nr+"]' name='daten_de["+daten_de_nr+"]'>";
        $("#dynamic_input_daten_de").append(e1);
        daten_de_nr++; 
        var e2 = "<input type='text' value='' id='daten_de["+daten_de_nr+"]' name='daten_de["+daten_de_nr+"]'><br>";
        $("#dynamic_input_daten_de").append(e2);
    });
    $( ".absenden" ).click(function() {
        $("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: setAttribute is normally not necessary, and since especially IE can be problematic with it, I’d recommend just using the syntax `input_1.type='text'; input_1.name='…';` etc. And setting the value explicitly to empty should not be necessary as well, since the default value is empty if nothing else is specified, so I’d not set a value at all.

Comment: I still got this Problem :(

Answer (score 0):

why you didn't use jquery? Your code will be better. And may be fixed your bag.

```
 var addInput = function() {
     var el = "<input value = '' name = 'name'>";
     $("form").append(el);
 };

 $("h3").on("click", addInput);
```

And try form submit with JS

```
var sendForm = function() {
 $("form").submit();
};

$(".some").("click", sendForm);
```

append to form this button

```
<button class = "some" name="Click">
```

Comment: Your right, the code looks better now, but this don't fixed the problem. (I edited my fist post.)